# Confused about usage of "div" in HTML

Tags: html

I was trying to convert a PSD into a webpage using HTML & CSS.

```
<div id="header-text-nav-wrap" class="clearfix">
    <div id="header-left-section">
        <div id="header-logo-image">
            <img src="D:\logo landing page.png">
        </div>
        <!-- #header-logo-image -->
    </div>
    <!-- #header-left-section -->
    <div id="header-right-section">**
        <div Id="member-login" class="member-login-box" style="width:218px; height:60px; background-color: #00B1F4;">
            <p>Member Login</p>
        </div>**</div>
    <!-- #header-right-section -->
</div>
<!-- #header-text-nav-wrap -->
</div>
<!-- .inner-wrap -->
```

Here, I have the problem with the bold part of the code. I was trying to align the text "Member login" into the middle of the rectangular box. Which is itself a "div" with specified size. So, as you can see, I simply created another "div" for text. But when I am trying to apply "vertical-align: middle;" on the "text div" it's not working. Also, when I am trying to apply "margin-top" on the same div, it's getting applied on the rectangular box.

Comment: Please edit for proper code formatting, and the slight language at the end of the post.

Comment: [*I'm using vertical-align:middle but it's not working!*](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/)

Answer (score 1):

*use this css -*

```
#header-right-section {
position: relative;
}
#member-login {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Don't forget to add vendor prefixes */
}
```

A `div` cannot be directly aligned vertically by the `vertical-align: middle` code. A trick using `line-height` suggested by Jared Farrish in the comments, will align `div` using `vertical-align`.

Comment: Mr. Rohit, a many thanks for helping. May I know how "position: relative/absolute;" works? And also, what are the roles of top & left?

Comment: I tried the same CSS code as you have suggested but it's not working.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the area 'Member Login'? and make sure the css code is not overridden by other css code you already have.

Comment: also, you can find a lot of detailed information about `position` and `top` and `left`, developer.mozilla.org provides nice information, you can take tutorial on w3schools also.. they will teach you in an easy and appropriate way...

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images.

Comment: I created rectangular box using HTML and in that box I wanted to add a text "Member Login" which should be aligned vertically as well as horizontally.

Comment: @RohitKumar - Sure you can [vertically-align a `div`](http://jsfiddle.net/xd52jf6x/).

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks for the clarification. The problem has been solved. I was able to change the vertical position of text by specifying "line-height" in the parent "div". I appreciate your help sir and Mr. Rohit Kumar

Comment: @JaredFarrish Nice trick using the `line-height`, can you do the same trick if the `height` of the parent `div` is not fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This CSS code allows you to place it without transformations. It's the best solution for me:

```css
div#member-login {
  position: relative;
}

p { /* better with an id or a class */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 16px; /* it's recommended to set it */
  line-height: 16px; /* the value should be the same as the font-size or the 150% of it */
  height: 16px; /* the value should be the same as the line-height property */
}
```